# Moving buildings in water layer into Buildings layer using MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo

I am using MapInfo.

I mistakenly vectorised some building on my water layer, is there any way I can fix this by moving the buildings in the water layer into the Buildings layer?

It was so tedious and doing it all over is not desirable.

Comment: Your question in its current state is not understandable. Please consider adding more information.

Comment: Also consider splitting your question into two separate questions as they don't seem to be related

Comment: There is probably an easy way to do what you want... but you'll need to add more details to get a sensible answer. We don't know anything about your layers, or the data (if any) attached to the lines/polygons. It sounds like you have two layers/tables. How many 'buildings' are we talking about? 2? 400? 8000? Is your question basically about whether you can copy lines from one layer and paste into another (yes you can)?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to make your Buildings layer editable.  Then, select the buildings from the Water Layer.  Then copy the buildings (CTRL-C) and paste (CTRL-V).  Because your buildings layer is editable, they will paste into that layer.

Save the Buildings layer.

Then, you can delete the buildings from the Water layer.

Comment: This would work assuming the two tables have an identical data structure. I think that's unlikely to be the case with a buildings and a water layer; I can't see that they would hold similar information. Copying and pasting between two different table structures is likely to leave you with a bit of a mess in the attributes table... If possible I would revert any changes, or go back to the original data, and start again. Just make sure you make the right table editable!

Comment: Thank you! That was so cool, I will figureout how to edit my attribute data correctly!

Comment: @T_Bacon, as he was just digitising it is unlikely there were any useful attributes so a copy paste should be a suitable option.